# pd dataframe from lists and dictionary using series

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have few lists and a dictionary and would like to create a pd dataframe.
Could someone help me out, I seem to be missing something:

one simple example bellow:

```
dict={"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": "text1"}
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l3 = ["x", "y"]
```

Using series I would do like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': pd.Series(l1), 'col2': pd.Series(l3)})
```

and would have the lists within the df as expected

for dict would do

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(dic.items()), columns=['col3', 'col4'])
```

And would expect this result:

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
1     x    a    1
2     y    b    3
3          c  text1
4
```

The problem is like this the first df would be overwritten by the second call of pd.Dataframe

How would I do this to have only one df with 4 columns?

I know one way would be to split the dict in 2 separate lists and just use Series over 4 lists, but I would think there is a better way to do this, out of 2 lists and 1 dict as above to have directly one df with 4 columns.

thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not build each column seperately via `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` instead of using `dict.items()`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': pd.Series(l1), 
    'col2': pd.Series(l3), 
    'col3': pd.Series(dict.keys()), 
    'col4': pd.Series(dict.values())
})

print(df)   
   col1 col2 col3   col4
0     1    x    a      1
1     2    y    b      3
2     3  NaN    c  text1
3     4  NaN  NaN    NaN
```

Alternatively:

```
column_values = [l1, l3, dict.keys(), dict.values()]
data = {f"col{i}": pd.Series(values) for i, values in enumerate(column_values)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
   col0 col1 col2   col3
0     1    x    a      1
1     2    y    b      3
2     3  NaN    c  text1
3     4  NaN  NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also use `pd.concat` to concat two dataframe.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': pd.Series(l1), 'col2': pd.Series(l3)}) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(dic.items()), columns=['col3', 'col4'])
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack zipped values of `list` generated from `d.items()` and pass to [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) for add missing values for match by maximum length of list:

```
#dict is python code word, so used d for variable
d={"a": 1, "b": 3, "c": "text1"}
l1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
l3 = ["x", "y"]


df = pd.DataFrame(zip_longest(l1, l3, *zip(*d.items()),
                              fillvalue=np.nan), 
                  columns=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
print (df)
   col1 col2 col3   col4
0     1    x    a      1
1     2    y    b      3
2     3  NaN    c  text1
3     4  NaN  NaN    NaN
```